# How to disable Visual Studio's autocomplete while in comments

Tags: visual-studio-2013, autocomplete, intellisense

Visual Studio seems to have some kind of limited auto-complete that occurs while typing comments. It seems to be listing classes, variables etc just to fill in their name. Here's an image showing it popping up while I type "form".

[image: Image showing the autocomplete]

I find this highly undesirable because comments are not usually code and I'm finding myself typing a common word (like "form") only for it to be replaced with the capitalized version because there's a class with the same name.

How can I disable it *only* in the comments? I do not want to disable it anywhere else nor make it harder to access elsewhere. Ideally I'd be able to manually open it with CTRL + SPACE or similar (right now that [causes a seemingly useless second menu to appear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY64e.png)).

Comment: That may well be the case. Some extensions I have installed include CodeMaid, GhostDoc, Productivity Power Tools 2013, and VSCommands for Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is being done by the Viasfora extension. It can be disabled from Options > Viasfora > General > Text Editor and set "enable plain-text completion" to be false.